# Поиск значений в динамическом текстовом файле от - до

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть динамический текстовый файл, в котором строка ROUTING TABLE и строка GLOBAL STATS никогда не изменяются. Всё что между этими строками меняется, т.е. (ip, mac) могут как добавляться, так и удаляться. Файл выглядит примерно так:

```
OpenVPN CLIENT LIST
Updated,Fri Jan  4 17:10:16 2019
Common Name,Real Address,Bytes Received,Bytes Sent,Connected Since
AABBCCDDEEFF,192.168.10.1:54054,82933647,38303313,Fri Dec 28 15:24:40 2018
A1B2C2D2E2F2,192.168.10.2:37007,75520723,36819438,Fri Dec 28 15:25:12 2018
A3B3C3D3E3F3,192.168.10.3:34977,556668317,387416490,Wed Dec 26 21:47:28 2018
ROUTING TABLE
11.11.11.1,AABBCCDDEEFF,192.168.10.2:54054,Fri Jan  4 17:24:03 2019
11.11.11.2,A1B2C2D2E2F2,192.168.10.3:60677,Fri Jan  4 17:24:02 2019
11.11.11.3,A3B3C3D3E3F3,192.168.10.4:34977,Fri Jan  4 17:24:04 2019
GLOBAL STATS
Max bcast/mcast queue length,0
END
```

В файл может быть очень большим, и в этом файле нужно выдёргивать IP и MAC, только между ROUTING TABLE и GLOBAL STATS. Как сделать так, что бы скрипт искал значения IP и MAC именно в диапазоне между двумя строками? Разбить сами строки могу примерно так:

```
info = {}
info['ip'] = line.split(',')[0]
info['mac'] = line.split(',')[1]
```

Но не знаю как сделать что можно было искать в диапазоне между ROUTING TABLE и GLOBAL STATS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Считываете построчно
- Находите строку `ROUTING TABLE`, поднимаете флаг
- Пока флаг поднят парсите строки
- Если встретили `GLOBAL STATS` выходите из цикла

---

Попробуйте:

```
text = """\
OpenVPN CLIENT LIST
Updated,Fri Jan  4 17:10:16 2019
Common Name,Real Address,Bytes Received,Bytes Sent,Connected Since
AABBCCDDEEFF,192.168.10.1:54054,82933647,38303313,Fri Dec 28 15:24:40 2018
A1B2C2D2E2F2,192.168.10.2:37007,75520723,36819438,Fri Dec 28 15:25:12 2018
A3B3C3D3E3F3,192.168.10.3:34977,556668317,387416490,Wed Dec 26 21:47:28 2018
ROUTING TABLE
11.11.11.1,AABBCCDDEEFF,192.168.10.2:54054,Fri Jan  4 17:24:03 2019
11.11.11.2,A1B2C2D2E2F2,192.168.10.3:60677,Fri Jan  4 17:24:02 2019
11.11.11.3,A3B3C3D3E3F3,192.168.10.4:34977,Fri Jan  4 17:24:04 2019
GLOBAL STATS
Max bcast/mcast queue length,0
END
"""

found = False
items = []

for line in text.splitlines():
    line = line.strip()

    if line == 'GLOBAL STATS':
        break

    if not found:
        if line == 'ROUTING TABLE':
            found = True
    else:
        ip, mac, *_ = line.split(',')
        items.append((ip, mac))

print(items)
```

Результат:

```
[('11.11.11.1', 'AABBCCDDEEFF'), ('11.11.11.2', 'A1B2C2D2E2F2'), ('11.11.11.3', 'A3B3C3D3E3F3')]
```

---

**PS.**

Если считываете сразу из файла, то вместо:

```
for line in text.splitlines():
    ...
```

будет:

```
with open('file') as f:
    for line in f:
        ...
```

Comment: Всё рабоатет, всё хорошо, но есть одно НО =)
делаю вот так
`items = {}
    else:
        items['ip'] = line.split(',')[0]
        items['mac'] = line.split(',')[1]
        # items.append((ip, mac))`
получаю `11.11.11.3
A3B3C3D3E3F3` как раз то, что нужно, но только последнюю строчку... А хотелось бы первую после ROUTING TABLE

Comment: @sakhalin, а вы сразу выходите из цикла как первую строчку с ip и mac получите, т.е. на следующей строке после `items['mac'] = ` вызывайте `break`

Comment: к сожалению не получается.

Comment: Словари в Python - неупорядоченные коллекции произвольных объектов с доступом по ключу.
ВНИМАНИЕ!!! `Значения ключей — уникальны, двух одинаковых ключей в словаре быть не может.`

`items` - должен быть список! `items = []`
Замените строку `items.append((ip, mac))`  на строку `items.append( {'ip': ip, 'mac': mac} )`  и посмотрите что у вас получилось.