# Поиск значения в текстовом файле, со следующий строки от искомой

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск, текстовые-файлы

Помогите решить проблему, есть динамический файл, в котором никогда не меняются строка **`ROUTING TABLE`** и строка **`GLOBAL STATS`**.

Нужно искать значения между этими строками.

```
OpenVPN CLIENT LIST
Updated,Fri Jan  4 17:10:16 2019
Common Name,Real Address,Bytes Received,Bytes Sent,Connected Since
AABBCCDDEEFF,192.168.10.1:54054,82933647,38303313,Fri Dec 28 15:24:40 2018
A1B2C2D2E2F2,192.168.10.2:37007,75520723,36819438,Fri Dec 28 15:25:12 2018
A3B3C3D3E3F3,192.168.10.3:34977,556668317,387416490,Wed Dec 26 21:47:28 2018
ROUTING TABLE
11.11.11.1,AABBCCDDEEFF,192.168.10.2:54054,Fri Jan  4 17:24:03 2019
11.11.11.2,A1B2C2D2E2F2,192.168.10.3:60677,Fri Jan  4 17:24:02 2019
11.11.11.3,A3B3C3D3E3F3,192.168.10.4:34977,Fri Jan  4 17:24:04 2019
GLOBAL STATS
Max bcast/mcast queue length,0
END
```

Каким образом можно это реализовать, чтобы поиск начинался от **`ROUTING TABLE`** со следующий строки.

---

Дальше разобью уже вот так:

```
info = {}
info['ip'] = line.split(',')[0]
info['mac'] = line.split(',')[1]
```

Comment: Поиск значений в динамическом текствовом файле от - до https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/931126/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%BE

Comment: @S. Nick дада, моё, решения так и не нашёл.

Comment: а что не так в том ответе?

Comment: Словари в Python - неупорядоченные коллекции произвольных объектов с доступом по ключу. `ВНИМАНИЕ!!! Значения ключей — уникальны, двух одинаковых ключей в словаре быть не может`. `items` - должен быть список! `items = []` Замените строку `items.append((ip, mac))` на строку `items.append( {'ip': ip, 'mac': mac} )` и посмотрите что у вас получилось.

Comment: @S. Nick абсолютно ничего не меняется, получается вывод `[('11.11.11.1', 'AABBCCDDEEFF'), ('11.11.11.2', 'A1B2C2D2E2F2'), ('11.11.11.3', 'A3B3C3D3E3F3')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text = """
OpenVPN CLIENT LIST
Updated,Fri Jan  4 17:10:16 2019
Common Name,Real Address,Bytes Received,Bytes Sent,Connected Since
AABBCCDDEEFF,192.168.10.1:54054,82933647,38303313,Fri Dec 28 15:24:40 2018
A1B2C2D2E2F2,192.168.10.2:37007,75520723,36819438,Fri Dec 28 15:25:12 2018
A3B3C3D3E3F3,192.168.10.3:34977,556668317,387416490,Wed Dec 26 21:47:28 2018
ROUTING TABLE
11.11.11.1,AABBCCDDEEFF,192.168.10.2:54054,Fri Jan  4 17:24:03 2019
11.11.11.2,A1B2C2D2E2F2,192.168.10.3:60677,Fri Jan  4 17:24:02 2019
11.11.11.3,A3B3C3D3E3F3,192.168.10.4:34977,Fri Jan  4 17:24:04 2019
GLOBAL STATS
Max bcast/mcast queue length,0
END
"""

found = False
items = []

for line in text.splitlines():
    line = line.strip()

    if line == 'GLOBAL STATS':
        break

    if not found:
        if line == 'ROUTING TABLE':
            found = True
    else:
        ip, mac, *_ = line.split(',')
        #items.append((ip, mac))
        items.append( {'ip': ip, 'mac': mac} )


for item in items:
    print("Ключ `ip`, значение {}; Ключ `mac`, значение {};"
      "".format(item['ip'], item['mac']))


Ключ `ip`, значение 11.11.11.1; Ключ `mac`, значение AABBCCDDEEFF;
Ключ `ip`, значение 11.11.11.2; Ключ `mac`, значение A1B2C2D2E2F2;
Ключ `ip`, значение 11.11.11.3; Ключ `mac`, значение A3B3C3D3E3F3;
```

Comment: оно=) спс, подпилил чуть чуть до нужного вывода, всё получилось)